# Draw a tree (literally) using Circles in Android - Not a Tree View Structure

Tags: android, canvas, tree

I have been struggling to draw a tree shaped structure in Android. I need to draw a tree shaped structure with branches at the bottom alone. The actual leaves of the tree will be represented in the form of circles. I have already started to draw circles by getting the width and height of the screen. My code is as follows:

Initially I've got the width and height of the screen:

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 display.getSize(size);
 int width = size.x;
 int height = size.y;
 System.out.println("Width is " + width + "Height is " + height);
 scrWidth = width;
 scrHeight = height;
```

And then I have created a Paint object with the same colors and iterated it through a `for` loop to draw circle multiple times:

```
 class Panel extends View {

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(20);
            paint.setStyle(styles[0]);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            setWillNotDraw(false);


            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

                x = (int) ((scrWidth / 360.0) * (90 + longitude[i]));
                y = (int) ((scrHeight / 180.0) * (90 - latitude[i]));
                paint.setStyle(styles[0]);
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);

                invalidate();
                System.out.println(x + "x" + name[i]);
                System.out.println(y + "y" + name[i]);

            }

        }
```

I have actually hard coded the values for lat and long as follows :

```
Double longitude[] = new Double[]{0.0,62.2,122.2};
Double latitude[] = new Double[]{40.2, 40.2, 40.2};
```

I dont want to hard-code the values of the lat and long but I am not sure what kind of mathematical calculations are required to find that dynamically so I am completely in dark. Would be great if someone helps me out !!! Any references that would help me pave the way to the final piece is most welcomed because I know that its a bit hard to find libraries or readymade codes for these kinda things.

**P.S :** I am actually not sure if OpenGL would help me out in these kinda things but I would love to get my hands on it so any reference to that is also welcomed.

Below depicted is a picture of what I actually I want :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the above tree using `Canvas` and `Path` class. Canvas for the leaves and the Path for the branches. It was a tedious and time consuming and I advise others not to take this route as it takes ever long to load cause its trying to do too much work with Canvas and I had memory issues frequently. I still face them. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Hi San, I am doing the same thing. Can you guide me for this ? As I have tried but didnt find anything online.